# How to align fields with printf

Tags: linux, awk, printf

the following syntax print the output1 down

```
echo "$status"
```

output1:

```
    component_name : TEZ_CLIENT     recovery_enabled : true
    component_name : WEBHCAT_SERVER         recovery_enabled : true
    component_name : YARN_CLIENT            recovery_enabled : true
    component_name : ZKFC           recovery_enabled : true
    component_name : ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT             recovery_enabled : true
    component_name : ZOOKEEPER_SERVER                      recovery_enabled : true
```

how to add the printf syntax in order to get the following lines:

expected output

```
    component_name : TEZ_CLIENT             recovery_enabled : true
    component_name : WEBHCAT_SERVER         recovery_enabled : true
    component_name : YARN_CLIENT            recovery_enabled : true
    component_name : ZKFC                   recovery_enabled : true
    component_name : ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT       recovery_enabled : true
    component_name : ZOOKEEPER_SERVER       recovery_enabled : true
```

Comment: can you post your initial `$status` content? (what gives `echo "$status"`)

Comment: I prefer not because it will print json file , and I just manipulate this file , in any case I want to add the printf to fix the four field

Comment: `json` - it's even better, cause I could suggest `jq` solution in that case

Comment: Yes, don't try parsing a JSON file with anything other than a JSON parser. It may work for one file and one situation, but as a general solution it will fail (since line breaks can happen between keys and values arbitrarily).

Comment: ok but in any case can you suggest how to enlightenment the four field

Comment: If jq still doesn't give you the desired output, I recently had a similar issue that I solved with an if/then construct.  You could potentially save the output of your `echo "$status" |tail -n+2 | egrep "component_name|recovery_enabled"` to a mapfile and run through it line by line with a `for` loop.  Tell it `if [[ ${#component_name} -lt '8' ]]; then echo $line | awk '{print $1,$2,$3"\t\t\t",$4,$5,$6}'` etc.

Comment: @Jesse_b please write your solution as answer

Comment: I can in a half hour maybe.  I have to wrap some things up first and would like to test it first before posting as an answer.

Comment: ok ,  take your time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
echo "$status" | awk '{printf("%s %s %-20s %20s %s %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)}'
```

Will produce

```
component_name : TEZ_CLIENT               recovery_enabled : true
component_name : WEBHCAT_SERVER           recovery_enabled : true
component_name : YARN_CLIENT              recovery_enabled : true
component_name : ZKFC                     recovery_enabled : true
component_name : ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT         recovery_enabled : true
component_name : ZOOKEEPER_SERVER         recovery_enabled : true
```

The `%-20s` format will reserve 20 characters for a left-aligned string, while `%20s` reserves 20 characters for a right-aligned string. Adjust the `20`s to fit your desired format.

---

In a previous incarnation of this question, you had various transformations using `sed` and filtering with `grep`.  It is likely these could also be done within the same `awk` script, directly from a source file.  Or, if the file is a JSON file (as you say in comments), directly by `jq` from that same file.

Answer (score 0):

Kusalananda's answer is much better than what I was thinking.  One thing I had in my construct though was a condition to truncate a column if it was too long.  I was able to implement this with his solution:

**INPUT**

```
component_name : TEZ_CLIENT     recovery_enabled : true
component_name : WEBHCAT_SERVER         recovery_enabled : true
component_name : YARN_CLIENT            recovery_enabled : true
component_name : ZKFC           recovery_enabled : true
component_name : ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT             recovery_enabled : true
component_name : ZOOKEEPER_SERVER                      recovery_enabled : true
component_name : ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_1234567890                      recovery_enabled : true
```

**SCRIPT**

```
# /bin/bash -
#
INPUT_FILE=$HOME/Documents/scripts/shell/testing/input
IFS= mapfile -t STATUS_ARRAY < <(cat "$INPUT_FILE" | tr -s " ")
for line in "${STATUS_ARRAY[@]}"; do
    COMPONENT_NAME=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $3}')
    if [[ "${#COMPONENT_NAME}" -gt "16" ]]; then
        echo "$line" | sed "s/${COMPONENT_NAME}/${COMPONENT_NAME:0:16}../" | awk '{printf("%s %s %-20s %20s %s %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)}'
    else
        echo "$line" | awk '{printf("%s %s %-20s %20s %s %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)}'
    fi
done
```

My script pulls the input from a file but you could likely also set your mapfile by `echo $status | grep..` or `echo $status | jq..`

**OUTPUT**

```
component_name : TEZ_CLIENT               recovery_enabled : true
component_name : WEBHCAT_SERVER           recovery_enabled : true
component_name : YARN_CLIENT              recovery_enabled : true
component_name : ZKFC                     recovery_enabled : true
component_name : ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT         recovery_enabled : true
component_name : ZOOKEEPER_SERVER         recovery_enabled : true
component_name : ZOOKEEPER_SERVER..       recovery_enabled : true
```